# PHP envia dados parciais para o mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

opa ! estou aprendendo a utilizar o trio html+php+mysql e o negocio esta me dando um baile. quando finalmente consegui entender os erros que eu estava fazendo, fui para o teste mais real, fiz um cadastro de login bem simples, o estranho, so envia o campo de senha para o banco o login e o email simplesmente nao vai.
os códigos: 
cadastro_login.html

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<html>
  <head>
     <title> Cadastro de Usuário </title>
  </head>

<body>

  <form method="POST" action="cadastro_login.php">
   <label>Nome</label>

   <br>
   <input type="text" name="usuario" >
   <br>

   <br>
   <label>Senha:</label>
   <br>
   <input type="password" name="senha" >

   <br>
   <br>
   <label>e-mail:</label>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="email" >
   <br>

   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="cadastrar">

  </form>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="index.html"> Início</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

cadastro_login.php

```html
<?php

include_once ('conexao1.php');

$usuario        = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha          = $_POST['senha'];
$email          = $_POST['email'];

$query= "INSERT INTO USUARIOS(usuario, senha, email) 
        VALUES('$usuario','$senha','$email')";

mysqli_query($db, $query);


?>
```

conexao1.php

```html
    <?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
//$database ="teste";

// Create connection
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or die ('Não foi possivel conectar ao servidor');
        mysqli_select_db($db, 'testa' ) or die(mysqli_error($db));


        echo "conectado";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom Dia Juliano ,

De um `var_dump()` na sua variável `$db` , você provavelmente vai notar que a mesma não apresenta valor algum (NULL), isso porque você chama o arquivo de conexão com o banco `conexao1.php` e simplesmente não o utiliza.

E segundo o documentação a função `mysqli_connect` espera 4 parâmetros e não 3 faltando você fornecer o nome do seu database fonte:http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php

Uma dica e você já montar um esquema de POO que ficaria mais o menos assim

```
class conectaBanco
{
   public $host = "localhost";
   public $user = "root";
   public $passoword = "";

   public function conecta{
   //Seu código

   //Dessa maneira você retorna o seu conector 
   return $db;
   }
}//fim da Classe

//Ai quando você desejar utilizar a conexão basta fazer o seguinte
include_once/require_once ('conexao1.php');

conexao = new conectaBanco(); //Esse é o nome da classe que agente criou anteriormente
$conn = conexao->conecta(); //Estamos acessando o método conecta dentro da classe conectaBanco e "pegamos o seu retorno que no caso é db.

 //dessa maneira conn está "carregando a sua conexão"

 //.. Restante do seu código

 mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Espero que esse exemplo te um uma clareada do que deve ser feito , recomendo que você comece a dar uma olhada no POO que é muito útil e que pode facilitar em muito o seu desenvolvimento.

Caso você não conheça o `var_dump` que é o melhor amigo do desenvolvedor php pois facilita em muito processo de "debbugar" segue o link da documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php e também a documentação em relação a `POO`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.php

Más caso você não queira desenvolver em POO seguindo a documentação basta em conecta_banco você colocar um `return $db;` e na cadastro_login fazer o seguinte `$db= include_once("conexao1.php");`  para mais detalhes é só dar uma olhada na documentação do `include_once`: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include-once.php

Comment: Valeu pelas dicas ! vou analisar com calma ...

Comment: o estranho é que depois que reiniciei ele funcionou normal ... a principio vou deixar como está,  como não sou programador e não vou ser, só estou fazendo porque já tentei 3 pessoas e as três disseram que iam fazer e nunca mais falaram comigo, vou tentar deixar o mais simples possível.